# eclipse+tomcat 8.0: 404 even after "use tomcat installation"

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, vaadin

I have downloaded the sample vaadin flow application and imported it into my workspace. I created a tomcat 8.0 server, and added *my_starter_project* as a web module. Also, in the "Server locations" menu of the tc 8.0 server, I checked "use tomcat installation". Still, it returns a 404 whenever I try to access `http://localhost:8080/starter/`

In the server.xml I seem to have the correct path set.

```
<Context docBase="my_starter_project" path="/starter" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:my_starter_project"/>
```

In the log file I also have several 404 attempts:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Mar/2018:14:53:37 +0100] "GET /starter/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1010
```

On the tomcat manager app it says that `starter` app is running, although clicking on it brings to 404.

The same project goes smoothly upon jetty:run

Comment: What happens if instead of `path="/starter"` you use `path="/"`?

Comment: @Morfic in that case the localhost:8080 url returns 404... weird. Though I am not sure if it is a good practice to set "/" as a path for a module/servlet.

Comment: I mean leave the path as `/` but still access your app with `/starter`. Additionally, how is your `UI` defined, does it have any path of its own?

Comment: @Morfic Well then it is 404 again. Actually that is what I would expect, since as I know if as web request arrives to localhost:8080/starter, then it is first processed by by the server application (eg. tomcat, glassfish etc.). It checks to which servlet  /starter should be routed to. Now /starter is not defined in server.xml anywhere. Regarding your other question, in the case of vaadin flow the @ Route annotation can be used on the  Component class (this is not a UI subclass). And in my case it is: @Route(value = "", layout = MainLayout.class). So I expect localhost:8080/starter/ to be valid

Comment: @Morfic just figured it out, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. In fact the problem was related to compilance levels. The pom of the example project had a source and target to java8 while my workspace default vm is jdk9:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

    <vaadin.version>10.0.0.beta1</vaadin.version>

    <jetty.version>9.3.7.v20160115</jetty.version>
</properties>
```

So it created a JRE System Library reference to jdk8... I changed 1.8 in the xml to 9 (not 1.9), refreshed the maven project, now it works on tomcat. It is also worth mentioning that with this compilance level jetty fails to run the webapp, but that's a different case.

I would have expected some backwards compatibility here, not sure why it did not work and why tomcat did not complain about the version difference.